# Mid 2015 MacBook Pro screen has worked intermittently over the last few years, why and how to fix

Tags: display, macbook-pro

Starting about two years ago my high end (then), mid-2015 MacBook Pro laptop screen would rarely start to go white while I was working and go super pale on me so I could not really see anything.  Moving the screen slightly would make it go back to normal.  After a while it got worse so I had to close and open the screen to make it start working.  This went on for about a year until it got really bad and I was having to open and close the screen every few minutes to use it.

The MacBook Pro was a substantial outlay for me and the a new screen replacement and install cost was almost the same price of a replacement laptop, so I just had to put up with it.

Eventually the whole screen went blank and for about a year, I had to use it as a desktop plugged into some monitors (with just vertical black and coloured lines or a pale white shadow visible on the laptop screen).

The last three months, I connected it to an old ACER monitor via a thunderbolt adapter and VGA cable.  I set the resolution to use ACER monitors settings (as the MacBook Pro screen was not usable anyway). The MacBook Pro screen started working perfectly again and I have even used it as a laptop.  Sometimes when not plugged into the ACER the screen goes all white again, so I plug it back into the ACER and after a while it starts working again.  Rarely it fails when plugged into the ACER monitor (screen gradually fades and goes white like before), but fixes itself after an hour or so plugged into the ACER.

The reason I am posting this is to try and work out what is going wrong.  It won't be the operating system because I have upgraded that over the course of this problem.  The actual screen looks great most of the time now.  Drivers are the same for everyone.  I wonder if it is because the ACER screen uses a lower resolution (it is a really old screen) and this somehow it "fixes it", but the question is what does it fix.  It was weird that opening and closing the screen fixed things in the beginning.

It is not financially an option yet to replace the whole screen as they are too expensive, but there might be other options if I can work out what is wrong.

Specific details on the Macbook are (as per request in the comments)

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- Built-in Display: 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800)
- ACER Display: Acer X193HQ Display 15.5-inch (1366 x 768)

Comment: I saw some others questions about MacBook Pro screens in SuperUser, so thought I would ask here, but please let me know if this is better suited to another part of StackExchange (instead of voting to close)

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to answer this but for there to be any real chance you would need to provide the specifics, i.e. which size MacBook and does it have a dedicated GPU

Comment: You should have contacted Apple about it when it first happened. They have recall & warranty repairs on many Macs. You're now probably far too late. There was a recall on some 2015 models, idk whether it's still valid. Maybe see if https://checkcoverage.apple.com/gb/en/;jsessionid=node0im8m56cpxfp416ipodgupn0b0507167.node0 gives you any info.

Comment: @JamesP I have added some details, is this what you were after, thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did contact them and it was not covered by their 90 day warranty, so I would have had to pay for a new screen and servicing, which was laughably expensive.  I got a few good years out of it and it still functions to some extent now, so happy I made the correct decision there.